# Output amount of instances in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

Let's say I populate a plane with points, each point is a rock, is there a way to count exactly how many instances are generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

**1.** You can simply hover over a socket to get a tooltip with the information:

[image]

**2.** You can use a *Viewer* node to get the relevant information displayed in the spreadsheet:

[image]

[image]

**3.** If you want to *use* that number inside your *Geometry Nodes* setup dynamically, you can employ a *Domain Size* node set to the relevant type (in this case, *Instances*):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all the different approaches, I tried the viewer node but couldn't figure out where the information was displayed.

Comment: Viewer node can a bit tricky to understand at first glance. In my screenshot the information is displayed where I'm pointing at with the red arrow, next to the category (it says Instances '40'). It's a simple setup with only a single source of geometry so it would show 40 even without a Viewer node anyways, but if you had many more sources, a Viewer node would limit that number to the node output you linked it to. Here an ex:  https://i.imgur.com/ITA1BOx.png I have 80 instances total in the whole setup, but the spreadsheet only shows the 40 I'm getting from the node I linked the Viewer to.

Comment: Let's say with the same setup, you wanna see the X positions of your instances as a list. You can do that like this: https://i.imgur.com/PjUuf1v.png They get their own special Viewer column. Be aware of what domain the Viewer is set to. By default, it's set to "Auto", but I find that it doesn't always work that well; be sure to set it something appropriate. Here with the same setup, I'm looking at the same Pos X values, but on the Point domain because I've linked it to the point distribution node. It also represent the values as color in the viewport: https://i.imgur.com/SAJ9qRE.png

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my wording, what I meant is I tried the viewer node before posting but couldn't figure it out until you provided your comprehensive answer above :)
But I do appreciate you further explaining ways to use it, especially the positioning stuff, that will for sure come in handy!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a node akin to `Distribute Points on Faces` to create them. In which case you can hover your mouse over the 'Points' output and a popup will appear noting the number of points.

See here:
[image: I hold my mouse over the output handling the information, and it appears.]

Hovering over any input/output dealing with that point cloud or set of instances should show a number of them.